# How to let method return more than one object?

Tags: java, methods, return

This is probably a very stupid question. But is there a way that a method could return more than one object? Like say, 2 Strings?

```
public static String multipleReturnMethod(){

   String a = "a";
   String b = "b";

   return a;
   return b;
}
```

Possible? Not Possible? How do you **make** it possible?

Comment: Not possible, instead use `java.util.List<String>`

Comment: Make another type that returns those values. Java is an object oriented language, yet people love to find ways to not make objects. =D

Answer (score 6):

You could return an array...

```
public static String[] multipleReturnMethod(){    
   String a = "a";
   String b = "b";
   return new String[] { a, b };
}
```

Or a list, or a type which encapsulates the two values, etc...

You can only return a single value from a method, but that value may itself give access to multiple "subvalues".

If you can give more information about what you're trying to do, we may be able to help more.

Comment: This works if the type of the multiple objects is the same (as described above). In the more general case of different types a wrapper class is needed. The array also has the disadvantage of the caller needing to know what index refers to a particular value (0 = a, 1 = b).

Comment: @John: It depends on whether they're different values with specific meanings, or whether it's really "the first value, the second value" etc. It's hard to know what the OP is really trying to do. (The "different types" is covered by "a type which encapsulates the two values".)

Answer (score 2):

Not possible without chaning the return object:

1. Either create a class for it:

   ```
   class Strings {
       String a, b;
       Strings(String a, String b) {
           this.a = a;
           this.b = b;
       }
   }

   public static Strings multipleReturnMethod(){
        return new Strings("a", "b");
   }
   ```
2. Or return an array

   ```
   public static String[] multipleReturnMethod(){
       return new String[] { a, b };
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the signature, you could concatenate the strings with a defined delimiter:

```
public static final String DELIMITER = "\t";  // or something else 
                                              // not used in strings

public static String multipleReturnMethod(){

   String a = "a";
   String b = "b";

   return a + DELIMITER + b;
}
```

(although I prefer changeing the signature and returning an array or a collection of values, see Jon's answer)

Answer (score 1):

If they are all the same type of object then the simplest way is to just return an array of that type of object

```
public static String[] methodA(){
  String[] temp = new String[5];
  // do work
  return temp;
}
```

If you wish to return different types of objects then return an ArrayList of objects.

```
public static ArrayList<Object> methodB(){
  ArrayList<Object> temp = new ArrayList<Object>();
  // do work
  return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in Java. You must create a wrapper class around the elements you want to return and return that single element and contains everything you want to return.

FunctionalJava has a handy class P for Product that makes this easy.
http://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/3.0/javadoc/fj/P.html

```
return P.p(a,b);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to return more then one object, never!.
Solution is to return an object wich contains the objects you want to return.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a more complex example, you can use a listener pattern

```
interface ResultListener {
   void resultOne(String text);
   void resultTwo(String text, int number);
}

public static void multipleReturnMethod(ResultListener result){
   result.resultOne("a");
   result.resultOne("b");
   result.resultTwo("C", 1);
}
```

As you can see you can return any combination of results to the caller with a mix or combination of types.

Answer (score -1):

One way is to pass an output object to your method, for example in the form of an arraylist, so it will be something like:

```
public static ArrayList<String> multipleReturnMethod(ArrayList<String> output) {

 String a = "a";
 String b = "b";

 output.add(a);
 output.add(b);
 return output; //not really necessary
}
```

Of course output has to be created outside your method.

Comment: The `return output` won't compile.

Comment: not only that... you're attempting to return an ArrayList<String> as a String...
`public static ArrayList<String> multipleReturnMethod("...")`

Comment: My bad - I shouldn't be doing copy/paste in a rush.